# Why does Jack hesitate when Nick is hanging from the pipe?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-score

In *The Score*, when Nick has already broken into the cage with the safe inside and is hanging from the beam waiting for Jack to kill the cameras, Jack is pretending to "have company" while actually doing nothing and waiting until Nick is about to abort the mission. He then proceeds to kill the cameras as planned.

Why the hesitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was not the hesitation.

Jack planned on to cross Nick after stealing scepter. He was setting up computers to resume security and cameras after a given time. You can also see him set timer on computer as well as his watch. He was only delaying the plan by passing some time being unresponsive.

Comment: The delay still makes no sense. Jack only starts the countdown and kills the cameras _after_ stalling Nick, not before. So he didn't gain anything from it.

Comment: @DoubleM: I guess the delay was to push off the schedule beyond decided time so that Nick will not have much time to escape through tunnel later on.